# Use Express.js's Request's generic argument in its extended properties

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to extend the Request type to add a property that depends on the request body, but the generic in `catchAsync` is not being properly applied, and it's always `any` instead of the generic argument passed

`index.d.ts`

```
import {RequestHandler} from 'express';
import {ParamsDictionary} from 'express-serve-static-core';
import {ParsedQs} from 'qs';

export interface CustomFormData<T> {
  data: T;
  fileNames: string[];
  buffers: Buffer[];
}

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request<
      P = ParamsDictionary,
      ResBody = any,
      ReqBody = any,
      ReqQuery = ParsedQs,
      LocalsObj extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>,
    > {
      formData?: CustomFormData<ReqBody>;
    }
  }
}
```

`middleware.ts`

```
import {Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';

export type AsyncRequestHandler<M> = (
  req: Request<any, any, M, qs.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction,
) => Promise<void>;

export const catchAsync =
  <M = any>(fn: AsyncRequestHandler<M>): AsyncRequestHandler<M>=>
  async (req, res, next) => {
    await fn(req, res, next);
    if (res.headersSent) return;
    next();
  };
```

`controller.ts`

```
  postProduct = catchAsync<IPostProduct>(async (req, res) => {
    const {data} = req.formData; // data is taken as "any" instead of "IPostProduct"

    await ProductController._productService.create(data);

    res.status(201).send();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you declare type `AsyncRequestHandler` with a generic, and then type the `req` Argument as `Request<any, any, M, qs.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>` it takes the default `any` type from the declaration merging. Here's one way about it -

```js
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request<
      P = ParamsDictionary,
      ResBody = any,
      ReqBody = any,
      ReqQuery = ParsedQs,
      LocalsObj extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>,
    > {
      // Change type from `any` to `unknown` for type narrowing
      formData?: CustomFormData<unknown>
    }
  }
}

export type AsyncRequestHandler<M> = (
  // Add a constraint for `formData` to keep it from taking 
  // the static type determined by the declaration merging
  req: Request<any, any, M, qs.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>> & {formData?: CustomFormData<M>},
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction,
) => Promise<void>;

export const catchAsync =
  <M>(fn: AsyncRequestHandler<M>): AsyncRequestHandler<M> =>
  async (req, res, next) => {
    await fn(req, res, next);
    if (res.headersSent) return;
    next();
  };
```

You don't really need the declaration merging if you take this approach, unless you want the `formData` to be available in all the places, mind that it'll still be of type `any` in other places without using the middleware.

Comment: The problem now with this approach is that no value can be casted from unknown:
`Type 'CustomFormData<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'CustomFormData<IPostProduct>`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a slightly un-elegant solution, replacing the `formData` prop in `AsyncRequestHandler`:

```
export type AsyncRequestHandler<M> = (
  req: Omit<Request<any, any, M, qs.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, 'formData'> & {
    formData?: CustomFormData<M>;
  },
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction,
) => Promise<void>;
```